# Java: How to create method createObject and eliminating duplication in HashSet?

Tags: java, duplicates, hashset

this is my first post on this forum and have issue with HashSet. I have three classes: Class Car, Main and CarManager. Class Car has String a and String b to create objects in HashSet. The CarManager has method "public Car createCar(String a, String b)" and should creates new entry to HashSet but first verify if car doesn't exist. CarManager should have collection of already created objects to perform such verification. Please advise how to resolve this task.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<>();
                cars.add(new Car("Ford", "White"));
                cars.add(new Car("Opel", "Black"));
                cars.add(new Car("Opel", "White"));
                cars.add(new Car("Audi", "Red"));

                CarManager carManager = new CarManager();
                carManager.createCar("Ford", "Yellow");

                System.out.println(cars.size());
                for(Car car : cars)
                    System.out.println(car);

               }
        }


public class Car {
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public Car(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Car)) return false;
        Car car = (Car) o;
        return Objects.equals(getA(), car.getA()) &&
                Objects.equals(getB(), car.getB());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getA(), getB());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "a='" + a + '\'' +
                ", b='" + b + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public class CarManager {

    public Car createCar(String a, String b) {
        Car cars = new Car(a, b);
        return cars;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking. Your `ObjectManager` class is never used. Sets already provide "deduplication", i.e. they can contain each value only once. Thing is: your `Object` objects do not override `equals` and `hashCode`, therefore Java cannot know if two objects have the same value.

Comment: Naming a class `Object` is a terrible idea. You shouldn't name you classes the same as base classes in Java.

Comment: This is ok, understand about use of "Object" and will avoid in future. I know that Set doesn't allow duplication but this is the task to write verification in method. Maybe I should use ArrayList for this task.

Comment: Object has equals and hashCode.

Comment: My method createCar does't work. This is my first issue. The number of objects in HashSet remains unchanged.

Comment: @DamianArciszewski `createCar` never adds your object the set, it only creates a new instance. You need to call `cars.add` if you want to put something into the set.

Comment: @knittl Ok, maybe the instruction wasn't entirely clear to me. The author wants me to create 3 objects of the Book class in the Main class using CarManager. CarManager needs to have Set and method createCar checking if object already exists. For now I don't have Set in CarManager and idea how to create method createCar.

Comment: @DamianArciszewski exist where? In the set? You can use `contains` to check that or look at the return value of the `add` method (`true` if it was added, `false` if it already existed). I'm confused by changing terminology all the time: initially it was Object and ObjectManager, now the question was updated to Car and CarManager and in your comment you write Book and CarManager. Why suddenly book? That makes it really difficult to follow and understand the problem.

Comment: @knittl Sorry, for confusing, disregard Book, this should be Car. I have changed all classes because of comment that word "Object" shouldn't be used in Class Name. I have 4 objects created in Main class and this objects should be taken for checking by createCar. I know construction of contains but don't know how to recall objects from the existing Set.

Comment: Again, if you have a set, use `contains` to check if an item is there, or test against the return value of `add`. I don't know what you are trying to do exactly, but if your manager needs to check for duplicate objects it needs to be aware of which objects exist. And that is only possible by somehow giving it a reference to the set (in the mathematical sense) of existing objects. You can do that by either holding a collection of objects inside the manager class, by passing the collection as method parameter or by having another global object which gives access to this collection.

Comment: @knittl Can you advise how to import "Set" cars from Main to CarManager for contains check?

Comment: @DamianArciszewski Any of the options I wrote in my latest comment: passing the set as method parameter; have it globally available; inject it in the constructor; …